# Why Optical Microscope can not be used for higher magnification

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science

Why optical microscope can not be used for higher magnification? Enlist different microscope used for higher magnification (> 2000 x).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the technicalities but I know that light cannot get you far enough because in order to see an object of a small size, the wavelength of the light used must be of similar wavelength and a small wavelength for light means high energy. Highly energetic photons then heavily disturb the state of the object you want to see making the whole magnifying procedure nonsense.

On the other hand, an electron microscope uses electrons whose wavelength is much smaller without having them speeding around fast enough to disturb your sample. In general, electron microscopes give some of the best magnifying pictures but I'm sure there are better ones.

I don't know the specifications of such microscopes or any other similar microscopes, but I'm sure it's easy to find them online with minimum effort.

Answer (score 0):

Of course a microscope can be built for higher magnification than the typical limit of ~1000x, but practically speaking it wouldn’t help you. You can magnify an image  arbitrarily large, but spatial frequency information will still be constrained by the diffraction limit, so you won’t gain any new information. Instead, you’d just be reducing your field of view for a fixed-size camera.